# Grouping Columns in Deedle

Tags: f#, deedle

Given a frame:`Frame<(string * int * int),int>`

```
let df = 
  [ (("N1", 100,1), "C1", 1.0); (("N2",100,2), "C1", 3.1)
    (("N3",100,3), "C1", 4.0); (("N4",100,4), "C1", -6.4);
    (("N1", 200,5), "C2", 1.0); (("N2",200,6), "C2", 7.1)
    (("N3",200,7), "C2", 4.0); (("N4",200,8), "C2", -2.4);
    (("N1", 100,1), "C2", 1.0); (("N2",100,2), "C2", 5.1)
    (("N3",100,3), "C2", 4.0); (("N4",100,4), "C2", -8.4);
    (("N1", 200,5), "C1", 1.0); (("N2",200,6), "C1", 1.1)
    (("N3",200,7), "C1", 4.0); (("N4",200,8), "C1", -9.4)]
  |> Frame.ofValues
```

I'd like to be able to group the columns by the second item in the Row Key tuple - so by 100 and 200 and then change the frame to `Frame<(string*int),(int*int)>`

It seems like I have to use `Frame.Transpose` and then `Frame.groupRowsUsing` to group the columns but I'm at a loss of how to get the 100/200 in the selector function.

Output should look like:

```
        (100,C1)   (100,C2)     (200,C1)    (200,C2)
N1 1 -> 1           1           1           1   
N2 2 -> 3.1         5.1         1.1         7.1 
N3 3 -> 4           4           4           4   
N4 4 -> -6.4        -8.4        -9.4        -2.4
```

Comment: In fact. your frame is Frame<(string * int * int),string>. Would you like to keep the original C1/C2 columns and the values to be a tuple or would you like the Column to be a tuple and the values floats as they are now?

Answer (score 0):

It was not clear to me if the intent was to keep the column keys as they are and change the row values to tuples or if the columns were supposed to be tuples and the values to remain as floats.

Assuming the first option:

```
//adding a helper function to the module: transforms row data and replace a given columns
module Frame =
    let mapiReplaceCol col f frame = frame |> Frame.replaceCol col (Frame.mapRows f frame)

(df,df.ColumnKeys)
||> Seq.fold (fun acc elem ->
    acc |> Frame.mapiReplaceCol elem (fun (_,k,_) row -> k,row.GetAs<float>(elem)))
|> Frame.mapRowKeys (fun (a,_,c) -> a,c)

(*output:
            C1          C2          
N1 100 1 -> (100, 1)    (100, 1)    
N2 100 2 -> (100, 3.1)  (100, 5.1)  
N3 100 3 -> (100, 4)    (100, 4)    
N4 100 4 -> (100, -6.4) (100, -8.4) 
N1 200 5 -> (200, 1)    (200, 1)    
N2 200 6 -> (200, 1.1)  (200, 7.1)  
N3 200 7 -> (200, 4)    (200, 4)    
N4 200 8 -> (200, -9.4) (200, -2.4) 
*)
```

Assuming the second option:

Step 1: descontructing the Frame to (row * col * value) and reconstructing

```
let step1 =
    df |> Frame.mapRows (fun (a,b,c) row ->
        df.ColumnKeys |> Seq.map (fun col ->(a,c),(b,col),row.GetAs<float>(col)))
    |> Series.values |> Seq.concat |> Frame.ofValues
    
(*
output:
          100                 200                 
          C1        C2        C1        C2        
N1 1 -> 1         1         <missing> <missing> 
   5 -> <missing> <missing> 1         1         
N2 2 -> 3,1       5,1       <missing> <missing> 
   6 -> <missing> <missing> 1,1       7,1       
N3 3 -> 4         4         <missing> <missing> 
   7 -> <missing> <missing> 4         4         
N4 4 -> -6,4      -8,4      <missing> <missing> 
   8 -> <missing> <missing> -9,4      -2,4   
*)
```

Step 2: reducing levels

```
let step2 = step1 |> Frame.reduceLevel fst (fun (a : float) b -> a + b)

(*
output:
      100       200       
      C1   C2   C1   C2   
N1 -> 1    1    1    1    
N2 -> 3,1  5,1  1,1  7,1  
N3 -> 4    4    4    4    
N4 -> -6,4 -8,4 -9,4 -2,4 
*)
```

Step 3 (optional): reacreating the tuples in the index

```
let step3 = step2 |> Frame.mapRowKeys (fun k -> k,k.Replace("N","") |> int)

(*
output:
        100       200       
        C1   C2   C1   C2   
N1 1 -> 1    1    1    1    
N2 2 -> 3,1  5,1  1,1  7,1  
N3 3 -> 4    4    4    4    
N4 4 -> -6,4 -8,4 -9,4 -2,4 
*)
```

Basically, we reconstructed the frame from scratch. Maybe a better approach would be to change how the original frame is being constructed instead of doing all this.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion - it was the latter. I'd like the column keys to be tuples and the values remain as floats. Can you update your answer, please?

Comment: Could you update your question and add an example of what the output should be (like the comment in my answer)?

Comment: Updated with output